# Terminal tab title not working correctly with MacPorts bash

Tags: bash, terminal, osx

I'm using OS X Yosemite 10.10.5. When using the default `/bin/bash` as your login shell, setting the following in `.profile`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD/$HOME/~}\007"'
```

sets the Terminal tab title to `~` when you are in your home directory, or `~/sub/dir` when in subdirectories.

However, Yosemite ships with bash version 3, and I prefer version 4, so I added `/opt/local/bin/bash` (which is version 4.3.42) to `/etc/shells` and used the `chsh` command to set my login shell to the MacPorts version. Everything else works fine, but when in my home directory, the tab title displays `/Users/mattdmo` instead of `~`.

Did the `PROMPT_COMMAND` syntax change with version 4? How do I get the functionality I'm looking for? On my Linux (Ubuntu 15.04) VM, I'm using bash 4 and the same command works fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works (i.e. escape the `~`):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD/$HOME/\~}\007"'
```